# Queue time for visa exemption when entering at Shanghai Pudong?

Tags: transit-visas, china, shanghai, customs-and-immigration

I'll be travelling through Shanghai Pudong Airport in 3 weeks and I want to use the 144-hour visa exemption service. I'm worrying about the queue time. I'll land at 1 p.m. and hope that it won't already be dark when I arrive in the very west of Shanghai. I've had the experience in Beijing of more than 3-hours queue time for the visa exemption and for the following regular passport control queue.

Does anybody have experience with that, how much did it take for you to get through  both queues? I've read [this post](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g308272-i2804-k9389267-o490-144_hour_Visa_Exemption_Transit_Policy-Shanghai.html) from March 2016 when this excemption was relatively new, somebody wrote on Tripadviser he had **no queue time at all**. Being a regular vistor of China, I'm having a very hard time believing this.

I would apply for a visa but, because in the meantime I'll be in need of my passport, I don't have enough time for the visa process.

Answer (score 1):

It takes about 2-3 hours to get through China using the 144 hour visa. If you're in a hurry pay for a Visa. The main line is triple the size but is very fast. The 144 hour visa has uninterested staff and they are SUPER slow. When I was there TWICE I got the vibe they do this on purpose.